# How to deal with commonlity between different union cases data?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I was happily using the following DU on my code

```
type Token =
    | LET of Position
    | WS of Position
    | IDENTIFIER of Position * string
    | EQ of Position
    | NEWLINE of Position
    | PLUS of Position
    | MINUS of Position
    | TIMES of Position
    | DIV of Position
    | OPEN_BRACE of Position
    | CLOSE_BRACE of Position
    | INT32 of Position * int32
    | FLOAT32 of Position * float32
```

Until I got into a situation where I needed to extract the `Position` out of a generic `token` variable. From my understanding there is no other option in regard to this situation other than straight refactoring it into something akin to

```
type TokenType =
    | LET
    | WS
    | IDENTIFIER of string
    | EQ
    | NEWLINE
    | PLUS
    | MINUS
    | TIMES
    | DIV
    | OPEN_BRACE
    | CLOSE_BRACE
    | INT32 of int32
    | FLOAT32 of float32

type Token = Token of Position * TokenType
```

Right? Defining a

```
let position = function
  | LET(pos) -> pos
  | WS(pos) -> pos
   ...
```

Would be just too painful. Or am I missing something?

Comment: There is probably a solution with reflection but I can't think of a type-safe one.

Comment: Seems to me that your refactored type makes more sense anyway.

Answer (score 5):

It makes more sense to go with the refactored types as the position is not a specific property of a token type but a general property of the tokens.

Using a tuple is the best here, but if you need to add more properties I would actually go with a record (maybe you will find out that as you continue developing it):

```
type Token = { Token_type: TokenType;
               Position: int;
               Length: int;
               ...
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you always can bind multiple patterns to one piece of source code

```
let position = function
    | LET(pos) | WS(pos) ...
    | FLOAT(pos, _) -> pos
```

This way, you only have to write the code of the function once, that said, a property that is general for all cases, imo does not belong to the cases, but as you wrote it after refactoring.

One might even argue, that you would probably have some function that would deal with the token(type) itself or extract an `int option` and another function that would use the position.

If so, you do not need to carry that many bindings around, as you can write functions that already require the `Position` or `TokenType` rather than a more complicated `Token.